# How to recognize the human voice by code in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-recognition, voice-recording

I want to integrate voice detection in my iPhone app. The iPhone app allow the user to search the word by using their voice. But, i don't know a single info about Voice Recognition in iPhone. Can you please suggest me any ideas,tutorials or sample code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach will probably be to:

1. Record the voice on the phone
2. Send the recording to a server that runs the speech recognition software
3. Then return something to the phone to indicate what it should do

This approach is favorable as there are a number of open source voice to text softwares out there & you are not limited by computing power in the backend.

Having said that, iOS has [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) which is based on Pocket Sphinx. It looks promising...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Google Chrome API to integrate voice recognition on your application, but there is a big problem : the API works only with FLAC encoded files, but this encoding isn't supported natively on iOS... :/

You can see those 2 links for more information :

- http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2011/09/objective-c-use-google-speech-iphone/
- http://8byte8.com/blog/2012/07/voice-recognition-ios/

EDIT :

I realized an application including voice recognition using Nuance SDK, but it's not free to use. You can register for free and get a developer key that allows you to test your application for 90-days. An application example is included, you can see the code, it's very easy to implement.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Well voice recognition is not correlated with iphone. All you can do is record the voice in iphone. Once done, you can either code your one voice recognition module, or find a third party API and reuse it.

You can do google search on that.